# Почему не происходит подключение к базе?

Tags: классы, php

Изучаю ООП в `php`. Написал простой класс для подключения к базе и создания таблицы. Не врубаю почему не работает, понимаю что не происходит подключение к базе в строке `$link=  $this->mysql_connect_djo();`, но не понимаю почему. Ткните меня носом знающие, пожалуйста!
Вот код

```
<?php
      $host = "localhost";
        $user = "test";
        $password = "123456";
        $database = "class2";
        $query = "CREATE TABLE notepad_info (
            id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
            fio VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
            notepad_text TEXT
)";

        class MYSQL_RABOTA {

            //подключаемся к базе
            protected function mysql_connect_djo() {
                global $host, $user, $password, $database;
                $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
                if (!$link) {
                    echo "Не возможно подключиться к базе" . " " . mysqli_connect_error();
                    exit();
                }
            }

            //Создание необходимой таблицы
            function create_table() {
                global $query;
                $link=  $this->mysql_connect_djo();                      
                if (mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
                    echo "Запрос отправлен";
                } else {
                    echo "Ошибка отправки запроса  ";
                }
                mysqli_close($link);
            }

        }

        $mysql_djo = new MYSQL_RABOTA;
        $mysql_djo->create_table();
        ?>
```

Comment: Изучающему - всегда пишите, *как именно* что-то не работает: ошибки, исключения, "белый экран", дым из системника etc. Если в ошибке указана строка - обозначьте ее в исходнике. Пока трудновато понять, почему где-то что-то как-то не работает)

Comment: не надо в классе global использовать, опишите логины/пароли в конструкторе, а параметры для создания таблицы в методе create_table, $link положите в $this->link; прямо в методе mysql_connect_djo.

в результате вызов должен быть примерно таким:

    $mysql_djo = new MYSQL_RABOTA("test","123456","class2");
    $mysql_djo->create_table("notepad_info",
            "id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT",
            "fio VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL",
            "notepad_text TEXT"
    )

Comment: ну и используйте объектный интерфейс mysqli , чтобы не переключаться туда-сюда. (http://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php)

Comment: Вот [тут][1] можете посмотреть пример.


  [1]: http://vazelin.org.ua/archives/342/izuchaem-oop-na-php-urok-1/

Comment: плохой урок.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы ведь не передаете параметры! Вообще я бы изменил класс так:

```
 class MYSQL_RABOTA {
        private host, user,password, database, link; //Добавлена строка;
        function __construct($host, $user, $password, $database) //Добавлена функция;
        {
         $this->host = $host;
         $this->user = $user;
         $this->password = $password;
         $this->database = $database;
        }
        protected function mysql_connect_djo() {
            //global $host, $user, $password, $database; Строка удалена;
            $this->link = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password, $this->database); //Строка отредактирована;
            if (!$this->link) {
                echo "Не возможно подключиться к базе" . " " . mysqli_connect_error();
                exit();
            }
            return ($this->link); //Строка добавлена;
        }

        //Создание необходимой таблицы
        function create_table($query) { //Строка отредактирована;
            //global $query; Строка удалена;
            $this->mysql_connect_djo();     //Строка отредактирована;                   
            if (mysqli_query($this->link, $query)) {  //Строка отредактирована;
                echo "Запрос отправлен";
            } else {
                echo "Ошибка отправки запроса  ";
            }
            mysqli_close($this->link); //Строка отредактирована;
        }

    }

    $mysql_djo = new MYSQL_RABOTA($host, $user, $password, $database); //Строка отредактирована;
    $mysql_djo->create_table($query);
    ?>
```

---

Кажется, так. Кстати, раз уже вы пишете объектно-ориентировано, то имеет смысл заменить процедурные вставки

```
mysqli_query($this->link, $query) на $this->link->query($query);
mysqli_close($this->link) на $this->link->close();
```

А еще можно так:

```
if (mysqli_query($this->link, $query)) { 
    echo "Запрос отправлен";
} else {
    echo "Ошибка отправки запроса  ";
}
//Заменить на:
mysqli_query($this->link, $query) or exit("Ошибка отправки запроса");
echo "Запрос отправлен";
```

Answer (score 2):

Один:
У вас функция коннекта ничего не возвращает. А неплохо бы, хотя бы линк вернуть.

Два:
начинать изучение ООП с global - дурная примета. =) Особенно, для той цели, для которой используете вы.

Лучше:

```
class my_class{
const db_name="db1";
const db_pass="db2";
```

Либо вообще в конфигурационный файл.